# CF9 Serializejson gives "out of memory" error

Tags: json, serialization, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to serialize a query to json. The query returns about 300.000 records. When serializing error 500 "out of memory" occurs.

How to solve this. Is there a way to directly stream the query to some file format?

Answer (score 0):

300 records shouldn't be enough to overflow the json library...

How much memory does your server have available / assigned to cf?

Can you paste a stack trace?

We use a handy little library called javacsv.
It is marvelous at creating csvs from arrays of strings. You simply add the .jar file to your class path, then create the java csv class, then call a bunch of methods to add columns or rows. It's good as it automagically quotes all of your data so you dont even have to think about it. It's fast too! I can post some code samples if you are interested.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/

CF9 has some spreadsheet exporting methods too, which you should probably check out if you haven't already.

http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#cfspreadsheet